# How to keep the keystore file private on flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-play, keystone

I'm trying to deploying my flutter app to Google play store as a test. On this document, https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/android, I think I need to store my keystone file private, but I'm not sure how to do it.

I'm completely a beginner to coding, so if someone can tell me how to make the file private, I want to know. I searched to make the keystone private, but could not find and I'm stuck now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It simply means keep to yourself somewhere safe. Don't upload it on public git-repo or anywhere. If you lose it then you might not be able to update your application anymore. If you're keeping it inside the app's project folder then add it to the .gitignore file so that it don't get uploaded in public git repo. If you're using private repo then you're good to go.